# Git branching/tag/version basics

Tags: git

I guess I still don't get git as I'd hoped...

I was creating a new branch, then going back, and I'm back farther than I intended. So I need to come forward to where I was Monday or so.

If I use the Git Gui "Visualize all branch history" tool, I can see all my versions, and I think where I want to be. So first question: how do I show that here?[image: Git visualization screenshot]

Then I'll just need to know the proper way to move forward to Monday's commit.

Thanks,

ed

Comment: Could you please clarify a little bit? As it stands, this is a bit confusing. Are you asking how to show your visual history on SO? In which case you could print screen and post the image with your question.

Comment: How did you checkout the previous commits?  Did you checkout a branch you created (git checkout <branch_name>), or did you checkout out a specific commit (git checkout <commit_hash>)?  Also, the more detail you can provide about what you've done, the easier it will be to help you.

Comment: OK, not perfect, but there's the gist of the git visualization

Garrett, I'm not sure what I did! I use TortoiseGit, which I'm cure was the first mistake, and did a switch/checkout on the entire project (I think) to return from my new (rails 3.1) branch to my old (rails 3) branch. Maybe I messed up on the tag?

Comment: could you define : "going back" .  And give us exactly what you have done?

Comment: So the place I want to be at is actually two commits later than shows in this view, but I'll settle for the 11/29 or 12/05 as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was to use Git Gui only very carefully. And to got to git log in the command line to really see what is happening.

The commits I wanted ended up being left only in an unexpected branch, and it took a number of selective merges to get them back.

Moral of the story:

1) Make sure everything is committed somewhere. You can always delete it from the repo, but not recover it if Git (with your help) drops uncommitted working directory files.

2) TortoiseGit and GitGui are nice tools. But make sure you learned the basics in the command line before you do a git reset -hard

:-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you created a branch of master but from a past point. (please correct me if this is not what you mean).
Then all you have to do is merge the extra commits that were done after , to do that:

```
git checkout <yourbranch>
git merge master

or 


git merge <commit>
```

Comment: Thanks, Wissam. I don't think so, it has been quite awhile since I worked in master.

Comment: gitk has a "reset Branch_002.7 branch to here" command. Maybe that's what I want?

Comment: I am curious did you just checkout to a previous commit then? if yes, then just checkout to the latest commit :).

Comment: I ended up finding the missing commits in the new branch(rails_3_1), but not in the one they were supposed to be in (002.7) Not sure what I did.